# Running Interactive .exe via ansible

Tags: automation, ansible, psexec

So I am attempting to run an .exe that I created using Auto IT. It simply makes two clicks on a program to perform a test and logs it. It wokrs fine if I am logged into the host and double click the exe.

I need to run this via ansible but I keep getting false positives. I am using the win_psexec module.
Ansible runs psexec with no problem and says it launches the exe successfully in the awx log.
When I log on to the host and check the log from the Exe, it has not been ran.

Here is the task being ran

- name: Run regedit.exe locally (on target node) as SYSTEM and interactively
  win_psexec:
  command: Myexe.exe
  interactive: yes
  system: yes

Any ideas on whats going on ?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't at all obvious if you look at the [documentation](https://fedorapeople.org/%7Etoshio/ansible/latest/modules/win_psexec_module.html) and the examples given. [I found another answer using win_cmd](https://lat.sk/2017/01/ansible-exe/) and was able to determine from that that you need to set the session to 1 for the remote user's logged in session.

Here's an example playbook that launches civilization 6 successfully on my windows workstation.

```
  ---
  - name: launch games
    hosts: win_tower

    tasks:
    - name: Run civ
      become_user: username
      register: results
      community.windows.win_psexec:
        chdir: C:\Users\username
        interactive: yes
        system: yes
        session: 1
        executable: C:\PROGRA~1\PSTools\psexec.exe
        command: C:\PROGRA~2\Steam\steam.exe -cafeapplaunch 289070 -login username password

    - name: Print results
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: results
```